# Удалить строку и столбец из матрицы

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки

Есть квадратная матрица размера N, задача состоит в том чтобы удалить строку и столбец матрицы на пересечении которых стоит максимальный элемент главной диагонали. Я решил создать новую матрицу и записать уже нужный массив. А дальше начинаются проблемы. Отдельно удалить или строку или столбец просто, но я не могу понять как можно сделать это вместе.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 6



int TheBig(int a[][N], int size) {
    int max = a[0][0];
    int i ,indx=0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i][i] > max) {
            max = a[i][i];
            indx = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The biggest number on the main diagonal is - %d\n", max);
    
    return indx;
}

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[N][N];
    for (i; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 50;
            printf("%3d   ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    int a1[N-1][N-1];
    int k = TheBig(a, N);
    
    

    /*код удаления строки и столбца */
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {

                a1[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];

            }
        
    }

    
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {

            printf("%3d   ", a1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Отдельно удалить или строку или столбец просто" - ок, сперва удалите строку, затем у получившейся матрицы удалите столбец. Чем вам не нравится такой вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужен другой массив, а нужно "удалять" с данного массива. Конечно размер статического массива не изменится, но вы можете задать новый размер, в пределах которого будете работать:

```
/*код удаления строки */
for (int i  = k; i < N - 1; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        a[i][j] = a[i + 1][j];

/*код удаления столбца */
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    for (int j = k; j < N - 1; j++) 
        a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1]; 

#define N1  N - 1   //новый размер
for (i = 0; i < N1; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < N1; j++) {
        printf("%3d   ", a[i][j]);
    }
   printf("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

алгоритм:

1. выделить память под матрицу `NxN`
2. заполнить матрицу соответствующими числами
3. найти строку и столбец `i` чей диагональный элемент максимальный
4. выделить память под матрицу `MxM`, где `M = N - 1`
5. пройтись по матрице `NxN` и перенести все элементы в матрицу `MxM` за исключением элементов на строке и столбцу `i`, т.е. m[k][l] = n[x][y]
6. освободить память из под матрицы `NxN`
   6.1) присвоить указатель новой матрице старой матрице

все, не надо ничего удалять из строк и столбцов - быстрее создать новую матрицу, заполнить и удалить старую

единственное, что матрицу придется создавать динамически:

```
int** matrix = new int* [N];

for (int index = 0; index < N; index ++)
    matrix[index] = new int [N];
```

ну или можете создать одномерную

```
int* matrix = new int [N * N];
```

правда придется к элементам обращаться через `matrix[i + N * j]` в этом случае